# how to properly pack a List<Hashtable<String,List<String>>> in an Intent for broadcast?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

On Android, I am trying to send a custom broadcast message using a custom Intent and BroadcastListeners. I have some custom data, in the format:

```
List<Hashtable<String,List<String>>> data;
```

When trying to use:

```
intent.putExtra("mydata", data);
```

I get the error:

```
The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the  arguments (String, List<Hashtable<String,List<String>>>)
```

Looking at the Intent class, there are a bunch of public methods that overload putExtra().  However, none seem to meet the data that I am trying to send.

There seem to be a rather generic method

```
putExtra(String name, Bundle value)
```

However, I am not sure how to transform my data in to a Bundle to use this.  Is this the right thing to do?  Or is there a simpler method?

Comment: OMG... RUN!! List<Hashtable<String,List<String>>>  .. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have Serializable for `putExtra(String name, Serializable s)` version. However, `List` is an interface that does not extend `Serializable`. Try to declare it as `ArrayList`.

Comment: thanks, by using ArrayList I was able to pass it to putExtra() with no additional work

Comment: Please be aware that using serialization is really expensive.  As the documentation says, it is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I used to meet the some problem. I solved it in a ugly way I think, you can take it as a reference.

I put a `Map` into a global singleton object, the key of `Map` is `String`, the `Map` will keep the object I want to pass into `Intent`, instead of putting the object into `Intent`, I put the `String` key into the `Intent`. In the `Activity`(or Service ...) where the intent was passed to, I get the key from `Intent`, and then get the object which I really care about from the `Mao`.

Maybe that's not clearly enough, here is pseudo code:

```
public void sendIntent() {
    Object data; // the object you want to pass through Intent
    Map<String, Object> globalMap = getMyGlobalMap();
    String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    globalMap.put(uid, data);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_OBJECT_UID, uid);
}

public void receiveIntent() {
    String uid = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_OBJECT_UID);
    Object data = getMyGlobalMap().get(uid); // Here is your data object.
}
```

Note that, since you put the global map in a singleton object, you may want to remove the object from the `Map` when you done with it, because the map will be there as long as your application live, you may not want to keep some useless objects and let them take your precious memory.

**Update**
Another very important thing is, the component which send the Intent and the component which will receive the Intent must be in the same process, only the classes in same process can share data in heap.

Comment: If you are doing this, good lord, just don't send a broadcast.  What in the world is the point of that?  Nobody but the same process can make use of the broadcast; just have a local object that you do a callback on.

Comment: @hackbod As I mentioned in my answer, I DO NOT think this is a good way to pass complex object through Intent. But if you just want to pass the object in you application only, and it's really complicated to make your object Parcelable(like `List<Hashtable<String,List<String>>>`), then I think you may want to consider this solution.

Comment: That is what I am agreeing with.  If you want to pass an object in your application only DON'T USE BROADCAST.  Broadcasting is for sending intents between applications.  If this is just internal to your app, it is a waste.  I *huge* waste -- both in CPU time because this requires at least two IPCs sending your entire Intent from the system and back to the app, and in your time because you need to ensure your data is placed in the Intent in a way that can be transported across processes.